# Strange brown/dead spots on leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves

What I have here is a plant which is being affected by something which is making certain spots of its leaves appear to be unhealthy.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Is this something that needs corrective action?

[image]

Comment: What kind of plant? (Despite your user name, it doesn't appear to be an avocado.) What environment do you have it in? What's the watering and feeding schedule?

Comment: Looks like *Pilea mollis*

Comment: Check and see if the plant's getting too much water. Is there sitting water at the bottom of the pot? If not, do you allow the top 1/2" of mix to dry between waterings?

Comment: Good question, I believe it's what J. Musser said. It's in a bedroom at the moment. The watering schedule tends to be sporadic....usually once or twice a day, with moderate amounts of water (a few squirts out of an old soap dispenser I'm using atm). Room is usually kept at 70 - 74 degrees. Checking for excess water in the pot, I stuck a pen down all the way, and the hole did not collapse upon itself, which I interpret to mean it's not saturated. The top does get mildly dry between waterings.

Comment: Is the plant kept on a windowsill, and how cold has it beent outdoors where you are? Is it contained in an outer pot or tray?